# SharePoint 2013 - 5000 List library Item

Tags: 2013, list, view, library, row-limit

In our company we recently moved to SharePoint 2013 Foundation version (on premise)

Now I have few list libraries which have move than 5000 record items on different sub sites. Currently the highest library have 45000.

Now I am unable to view them or select the custom views that we created to filter / group the list. After reading some blogs I changed the limit to 50000 in the central administration. Then everything works fine. However as recemommed by many users if this limit is increased in central administration it can slow down the Sharepoint performance. So I had to reset it back to default 500

Please could some guide me in step by step what is the work around for this or how can I resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

The List View Threshold is by default 5000 items.
This limitation is due to the way how SharePoint works, especially related to SQL server queries.

The best way is to separate the library (libraries) (and the content inside) using relevant approach (i.e. alphabetically or by project or any other suitable option) in such way that every library contains < 5000 elements.

Also, consider adding indexes to fields (columns), it may help.

Please also refer to design guidelines\explanations:

[Designing large lists and maximizing list performance (SharePoint Server 2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813(v=office.14).aspx)

[Working with Large Lists in SharePoint 2010 – List Throttling](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/02/28/working-with-large-lists-in-sharepoint-2010-list-throttling/)

[Manage large lists and libraries in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-SharePoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59)